# Using .promise() to have the Ajax request start first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I was advised to use `.promise()` in this function because as it is now, the Ajax call won't start until the loading animation has finished. I read through the codex, but couldn't really understand how to implement it. Can someone show me how it's done?

```
    function projectShow() {
        $('#loading-animation').show(100, function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: ajaxURL,
                data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#project-container').slideDown('fast').html(response);
                    $('#loading-animation').hide();
                return false;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: The question is not clear. "Can someone show me how it's done?" --- what "it"? Technically there is no difference between using `success` callback and promises.

Comment: I just wasn't sure how to use jQuery's `.promise()`. But if there is no difference then I guess I don't have to worry about it. Thank you.

Comment: "the Ajax call won't start until the loading animation has finished". So what? What would you like to have happen instead?

Comment: @chiliNUT I'd like the Ajax request to start first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice to use `.promise()` was probably given because your code forces a small 100ms delay before making the AJAX call (while the animation runs to completion). It may make more sense to make the AJAX call, then start the animation while waiting for the response.

I have modified your code to achieve this by simply making the AJAX call before starting the animation. (`jQuery.ajax()` uses `.promise()` internally by default. See the `async` option for more information.) Be aware that in cases where the AJAX call returns in less than 100ms, the execution order of your JavaScript may be altered. This may cause undesired side-effects, but I think it is OK in your case.

```
function projectShow() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#project-container').slideDown('fast').html(response);
            $('#loading-animation').hide();
        return false;
        }
    });
    $('#loading-animation').show(100);
}
```

Comment: "Be aware that in cases where the AJAX call returns in less than 100 ms, the execution order of your JavaScript may be altered." --- it cannot be. JS is single threaded

Comment: @zerkms: JS is single threaded, but has an execution queue. Imagine the AJAX call only takes 50 ms. The original code would call `$('#loading-animation').show(100);` first, then `$('#loading-animation').hide();` The code I suggested would call `$('#loading-animation').hide();` first, then `$('#loading-animation').show(100);`

Comment: nope. `$('#loading-animation').show(100);` is **guaranteed** to be invoked **before** ajax callback (even if ajax call takes 0ms)

Comment: @zerkms: OK, that was a bad example. But what if you add a `complete` callback: `$('#loading-animation').show(100, complete);`? The order of calls to AJAX `success` and `complete` callbacks would be different, no?

Comment: Then - yes, it will be different.